Lookup field has unexpected value when accessed
I am testing new logic I added in an apex class that is called from a batch class.
This is the method I added:
public static List<Price_Infractions_History__c> processInfractions(List<Product_Tracked__c> tracked, Map<Id, Decimal> mapPreviousPriceDiff){
    System.debug('tracked: ' + JSON.serialize(tracked));
    List<Price_Infractions_History__c> toUpsert = new List<Price_Infractions_History__c>();

    Decimal exchangeRate = [SELECT Default_Currency_id__r.Agreed_Price_ML_Exchange_Rate__c FROM Site__c WHERE Id = :tracked[0].Tracking__r.Item__r.Site__c].Default_Currency_id__r.Agreed_Price_ML_Exchange_Rate__c;

    Formula.recalculateFormulas(tracked);

    Map<Id, Price_Infractions_History__c> mapCorrections = new Map<Id, Price_Infractions_History__c>();
    for(Product_Tracked__c prod : tracked){
        System.debug('prod.ML_User__r.Infractions_History_Log__c: ' + prod.ML_User__r.Infractions_History_Log__c);
        if(prod.ML_User__r.Infractions_History_Log__c == false) continue;
        
        if(generatesInfractionLog(prod, mapPreviousPriceDiff.get(prod.Id))){
            toUpsert.add(createInfractionLog(prod, exchangeRate));
            prod.Last_Infraction_Date__c = Datetime.now();
        }else if(generatesCorrectionLog(prod)){
            Price_Infractions_History__c correction = createInfractionLog(prod, exchangeRate);
            toUpsert.add(correction);
            mapCorrections.put(correction.Product_Tracked__c, correction);
            prod.Last_Infraction_Date__c = null;
        }
    }

    for(Price_Infractions_History__c infraction : [SELECT Id, Product_Tracked__c FROM Price_Infractions_History__c WHERE Product_Tracked__c IN :mapCorrections.keySet() AND Correction_Date__c = null LIMIT 9000]){
        toUpsert.add(new Price_infractions_History__c(Id = infraction.Id, Correction_Date__c = mapCorrections.get(infraction.Product_Tracked__c).Correction_Date__c));
    }

    return toUpsert;
}

This is the execute block of the batch class:
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Product_Tracked__c> scope){
    ContextManager.instance = ctx;
    Map<String, List<Product_Tracked__c>> productsByName = new Map<String, List<Product_Tracked__c>>();
            
    //inicializo el map de mensajes que usa el trigger para no perder su estado
    TrackingDataLog.messages = trackingMessages;
    TrackingAlertAttachmentController.messages = csvs;
    
    Map<Id, Decimal> mapPreviousPriceDiffs = getPreviousPriceDiff(scope);
    
    ProductTrakingController.updateFromItems(scope);

    ctx.root.addErrors(Database.upsert(ProductTrakingController.processInfractions(scope, mapPreviousPriceDiffs), false));
    ctx.root.addErrors(Database.update(scope, false));

    deleteInvalidTrackings(scope);
    
    //Recupero el map de mensajes que usa el trigger para no perder su estado
    trackingMessages = TrackingDataLog.messages;
    csvs = TrackingAlertAttachmentController.messages;
    
    TokenRefreshingController.getInstance().flush();
}

As you can see, if prod.ML_User__r.Infractions_History_Log__c == false, I ignore the current object.
This is my unit test method:
 @isTest
 public static void testPriceInfractionHistory(){
      TestFactory instance = TestFactory.instance;

      Currency__c crcy = instance.create(new Currency__c(ML_ID__c = 'ARS'));

      instance.insertAllByDependencies();

      Site__c site = new Site__c();
      site.Name = 'MLA';
      site.Name__c = 'MLA';
      site.Default_Currency_Id__c = crcy.Id;
      insert site;

      Item__c item = TestTool.getItem();
      item.Stop_Time__c = Datetime.now().addDays(40);
      item.Site__c = site.Id;
      insert item;

      ML_User__c mluser = TestTool.getMlUser();
      insert mluser;
      
      String mluserid = mluser.id;
      mluser.ML_ID__c = mluserid.substring(0,15);
      mluser.Infractions_History_Log__c = true;
      update mluser;

      System.debug(mluser);

      Tracking__c tracking = new Tracking__c();
      tracking.Name = 'TEST 123';
      tracking.Item__c = item.ID;
      tracking.Agreed_Price_ML__c = 40;
      tracking.Currency__c = crcy.Id;
      insert tracking;

      Product_Tracked__c tracked = new Product_Tracked__c();
      tracked.Name = 'MLA485030684';
      tracked.Points__c = 10;
      tracked.Title__c = 'test';
      tracked.Stop_Time__c = Datetime.now().addDays(40);
      tracked.Price__c = 45;
      tracked.Sold__c = 10;
      tracked.Listing_Type__c = 'gold';
      tracked.Tracking__c = tracking.ID;
      tracked.Unique_ID__c = 'TEST 123TEST2'; 
      tracked.Seller_Name__c = 'test';
      tracked.Status__c = 'active';
      tracked.Currency__c = crcy.Id;
      tracked.ML_User__c = mluser.Id;
      insert tracked;

      BatchApexProductTracking batch = new BatchApexProductTracking();
      Test.startTest();
      Database.executeBatch(batch, 1);
      Test.stopTest();
 }

As you can see, The Ml_User object has that field set as true in my test method and I assign it to the relevant object Product_Tracked.
For some reason, on the processInfractions method, that value is false, when it should be true.
This field is new, I know it isn't being modified by any other flow or trigger before this.
I can confirm this because in the debug log, the VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT of the "tracked" variable parameter, shows the related object with the field and its correct value:

But then, the first system.debug shows no lookup fields and the debug when I log the actual value, it reads false:

Some behiavour I've never encountered is happening here and any help to understand it would be appreciated. I've checked the logs numbers of times already and I can't find the issue.

None of the previous logic before my method changes either the ML_User lookup field or the specific value I need, just in case anyone wonders.


Are you certain you have successfully deployed the latest version of all of the code to the org? Is there any automation (flows etc.) that might be changing this field value? Have you tried enabling field history tracking against the field to see how it is behaving?

@PhilW yes, all the code is deployed. There are no automations, this field was created only and only for this logic alone (checked just in case the where is this used, only my classes appear)

@PhilW how can I interpret that the "tracked" list parameter has the correct field value (see the log image) but then it has no longer that value when I access it? does the recalculateFormulas() method affect lookup related fields in any way, even if they are not formulas?

Recalculating formulas does not impact non-formula fields. Are you 100% sure you correctly query the data again?

@PhilW what do you mean by query the data again? I only query the records once, on the start method of the batch class. In that query I included that field. You mean I have to re-query after the formula calculations?

Your code snippets above do not show how you query the User records with the Infractions_History_Log__c field populated, so I don't know if you are correctly querying the data.
